# R factor all columns containing string

Tags: r

I have many dataframe columns I wish to convert to factors without factoring each separate field. How can iterate over the column names and if any match a regular expression convert them to factors? I am coming from the Python world, and I don't yet understand looping and string substitutions in R.

Pseudo code:

```
    for name in df.columns.names:
        if name matches "regex":
            df$name <- factor(df$name)
```

Comment: `df = lapply(df, function(x) if (is.character(x)) return(factor(x)) else return(x))`.

Comment: But the best place to make these changes is when you read in data. See the column classes argument of whatever you're reading data in with.

Comment: `library(dplyr) ; df %>% mutate_each(funs(factor), matches('regex'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably:

```
 df[  , grepl('regex' , names(df)) ] <- 
                                   lapply( df[  , grepl('regex' , names(df)) ], factor)
```

Could also use `grep` in this case. The `j` argument of `[` and `[<-` can take either logical or numeric arguments.

Comment: I'd probably save off the `grepl(...)` to `idx` or something, then you can just do a cleaner statement like `df[idx] <- lapply(df[idx], factor)`

Comment: @thelatemail  I don't understand what "idx" is. Where does the regular expression check happen without grep?

Comment: @erics - `idx <- grepl('regex' , names(df))` - run that first so you don't have to repeat the code twice.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `type.convert`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
```